# Whether Demultiplexer and Decoder are same terms or different one?

Tags: digital-logic

I'm really confused between above these terms.  First I want to clarify what I understood till now.

> 1. In Demultiplexer, there is one input and many outputs. Whereas in Decoder, there are many inputs and many outputs.
> 2. In Demultiplexer, there are control/ select lines present whereas in Decoder there are no such control/ select lines present.

But on some websites and books also these two terms are used interchangeably . Here is an example [IC 74138 datasheet](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT138.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjw5MOoidLOAhUJvBoKHabWBXUQFggsMAE&usg=AFQjCNGG2VqVUSLx2saEARRP7yMK-1WIjA) .

So can anyone tell me whether Decoder and Demultiplexer are same terms or different one? If different, how?
Also, where Demultiplexer is uses and where Decoder are used perticularly?

Answer (score 3):

They are different terms. 74HC138 can be used both as a decoder and a demultiplexer.

- As a decoder: Inputs A0, A1, A2 (many inputs) take a binary encoded signal and the result is decoded to Y0..Y7 (many outputs.) Refer to page 4(Table 3) of the datasheet you are specifying for a complete truth table.
- As a demultiplexer: The input is E3 (one input) and depending on the values of A0, A1, A2 (control lines), the value of E3 is routed to one of the Y outputs (many outputs.)

The difference may appear subtle at first glance but is a very important one. In fact, decoder and demultiplexer are two of the basic concepts of digital circuits. If some websites or books treat them interchangeably it would be because the writer is careless.

[This page](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_5.html) has a quite comprehensive explanation of what a decoder is.

[This page](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_3.html) has an explanation of what a demultiplexer is.

Answer (score 1):

A demultiplexer is a rather specific term, used for the function (chip, logic block, piece of code, etc) that splits the data that has been multiplexed into on channel back out to multiple channels. One data input, multiple data outputs, but there can be other inputs (like the ABC inputs for a logic demux chip).

A decoder is a more general term, used for a function that removes an enconding that was previously applied from an input data channel. A demuliplexer can be regarded as one specific form of decoder.

Comment: In VLSI a decoder is usually used to convert a binary to a one-hot representation.  For example a 3-8 decoder makes 000=00000001 and 010=00000100

Comment: That is a specific use of the term.

Comment: I did not mean to imply otherwise.  But in VLSI circles if you mention decoder, that will be the first thing that they think of.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, until I came across this thread. But, as useful as the answers are, they do not answer my question; which is: What is the difference between a decoder & a demultiplexer and why would you choose one over the other in a design?

Apart from the fact that they are constructed & operated differently, they both perform the same function.

I was also of the opinion that demultiplexer splits the data that has been multiplexed into on channel back out to multiple channels. 

However, upon testing the circuit model, it functioned very much like a decoder.